# BillingClient.FeatureType - Which Type to Use

Tags: android, in-app-billing

The google play billing overview states:

> before your app enters the billing flow, call isFeatureSupported() to
>   check that the device supports the products you want to sell. For a
>   list of product types, see BillingClient.FeatureType.

The documentation for Feature type lists the following types:

> IN_APP_ITEMS_ON_VR
>
> PRICE_CHANGE_CONFIRMATION
>
> SUBSCRIPTIONS
>
> SUBSCRIPTIONS_ON_VR
>
> SUBSCRIPTIONS_UPDATE

What is meant by "ON_VR"?  The documentation does not elaborate on this.

Since there is only one IN_APP_ITEMS* possibility, am I to assume that this should be used to verify device support for all in-app items?  The documentation states "Purchase/query for in-app items on VR." which isn't very helpful.

If I wanted to confirm support for subscriptions, which one would I use, SUBSCRIPTIONS or SUBSCRIPTIONS_ON_VR?  Why would I choose one over the other?

Here is the link:

[BillingClient.FeatureType](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.FeatureType#in_app_items_on_vr)

Thanks in advance for any help clarifying this

Comment: got any update on the "VR"?

Comment: @Ankur_009 I did a lot of searching back during the time when I posted this.  I recall eventually finding some references to virtual reality.  I came to conclude with about 90% certainty that the VR stands for virtual reality.  My app did not support virtual reality, so in the end, I just ignored the "VR" feature types and everything worked out fine in my case.

Comment: thanks. Can you suggest some reference or any link?

Comment: @Ankur_009 I don't recall there being any one point of reference I could find.  I drew my conclusion based on pieces of information I found in various locations, one being that Google was working on an in-app billing feature that supports virtual reality

Answer (score 2):

**IN_APP_ITEMS_ON_VR** and **SUBSCRIPTIONS_ON_VR** maybe reserved for future use, because I didn't see any mention of them in Google docs about in-app billing (in the web too).

All versions of Play Store support regular in-app products ("Managed products" in Google Play Console), so you can't check whether they are supported or not. Subscriptions support should be checked via **SUBSCRIPTIONS** feature.

Comment: There are three types of in-app products listed in the google play console, managed products, subscriptions and rewarded products.   What did you mean by "regular in-app products"?

Comment: Managed products, because support for rewarded products were added just in Play Billing Library 1.2.1 and subscriptions aren't supported by default (as mentioned in answer). I corrected my answer.